# How to reach ELO Rating 2000?

Tags: elo

I started playing chess a year ago, now my chess ELO rating is 750.

How much time it takes for me to reach 2000 ELO rating assuming i play 2 hours of chess everyday?

Is working on ELO rating important at all?

Comment: 750?? Are you sure it's not 1750?

Comment: To answer "Is working on ELO rating important at all?", the answer is no. What is important is to enjoy the game.

Comment: Working hard every single day may get you there, many ways of going about, unsure what will work. I suggest getting a coach for a few lessons. Playing constantly is essential,  but if youre not studying or learning somehow,  you might as well give up.